# Can't I downcast inside a switch ? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I have 2 segues in the same prepareForSegue, one connects to a UIViewController subclass and the other connects to a UICollectionViewController subclass.
I'm trying to use a switch/case with polymorphism to set my destinationViewController but the downcast I do inside the switch is not visible outside it, it keeps seeing the var as UIVC as declared originally. What am I doing wrong here ?
The error is "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'context'"

```
 let identifier: String!
 var destinationTest: UIViewController!

    switch identifier {
    case "Add Exercise":
            destinationTest = segue.destination as! AddExerciseViewController
    case "addExerciseInCollectionView":
            destinationTest = segue.destination as! AddExerciseCollectionVC
    default: 
         break
    }

 destinationTest.context = self.context
```

Comment: `destinationTest` is declared as a `UIViewController` so that is all you will have for the variable. It may point to other subclasses of `UIViewController` but you won't be able to access any subclass specific properties/functions using the `UIViewController` variable. FYI - this has nothing to do with using a `switch`.

Comment: For the code you have to work, your two view controller classes either need to share a superclass (or better) implement a protocol where the `context` property is introduced. You can then use that class/protocol instead of `UIViewController` as the type of `destinationTest`

Comment: Ok, they both inherit from UIViewController, however,  the context property is declared in a third subclass of UIViewController, a sibling subclass.
I got now why even after the downcast those two controllers can't see my property. I thought that was a problem of scope inside the switch, lol.
Thank you very much guys !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RMaddy said, you have declared `destinationTest` as `UIViewController`, so even though you are assigning specific `UIViewController` subclasses *inside* the switch, all the compiler knows is that `destinationTest` is a `UIViewController`, so you can't access any subclass properties via this variable.

You either need your two view controller subclasses to inherit from a common superclass, which defines the `context` property and declare `destinationTest` to be of that superclass, or use a protocol that provides the `context` property:

```
property HasContext {
    var context: Context { set get }
}

class AddExerciseViewController: UIViewController, HasContext {

    var context: Context

    ...
}

class AddExerciseCollectionVC: UIViewController, HasContext {

    var context: Context

    ...
}
```

Then you can say

```
let identifier: String!
var destinationTest: HasContext!

switch identifier {
    case "Add Exercise":
            destinationTest = segue.destination as! HasContext
    case "addExerciseInCollectionView":
            destinationTest = segue.destination as! HasContext
    default: 
         break
 }

 destinationTest.context = self.context
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view controllers would need to conform to a protocol that has `context`, otherwise just consider doing them individually.

```
switch (segue.identifier, segue.destination) {
case ("Add Exercise", let controller as AddExerciseViewController:
    controller.context = self.context
case ("addExerciseInCollectionView", let controller as AddExerciseCollectionVC:
    controller.context = self.context
default: 
     break
}
```